# Variables inside ng-template is unresolved

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-template

I am trying to create a crud page in angular 14.2.0, using angular material ^14.2.2, angular localize ^14.2.2, now when I try to bind/access a variable inside ng-template, I get `Unresolved variable error` inside IDE and also in browser.

Here is my html template:

```
<!-- Container -->
<div class="table-container">
    <!-- Create Button -->
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="create-button" (click)="openCreateModal()">Create</button>

    <!-- Table -->
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

        <!-- Column Definitions -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="user_id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> User ID </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{ user.user_id }} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="first_name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> First Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{ user.first_name }} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="last_name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{ user.last_name }} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
                <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="openEditModal(user)">
                    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="deleteUser(user)">
                    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Table Header -->
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>

        <!-- Table Rows -->
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let user; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>

    <!-- Pagination -->
    <mat-paginator [length]="dataSource.length" [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
                   (page)="onPageChange($event)">
    </mat-paginator>
</div>


<!-- Create/Edit Modal -->
<ng-template #modalTemplate let-modalUser>
    <div class="modal" [ngClass]="{'open': isModalOpen}">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h2>{{ modalTitle }}</h2>
            <form (ngSubmit)="saveUser()">
                <!-- Input fields for creating/editing user data -->
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput placeholder="First Name" [(ngModel)]="modalUser.first_name" name="firstName" required>
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" [(ngModel)]="modalUser.last_name" name="lastName" required>
                </mat-form-field>
                <div class="modal-actions">
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Save</button>
                    <!--<button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">{{ modalAction }}</button>-->
                    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

And here is my ts file:

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog} from "@angular/material/dialog";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-company-crud-component',
  templateUrl: './company-crud-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./company-crud-component.component.scss']
})
export class CompanyCrudComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'actions'];
  dataSource: any[] = [];

  pageSize = 5;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 25, 100];


  // Modal properties
  isModalOpen = false;
  modalTitle = '';
  modalAction = '';
  modalUser: any = {};

  @ViewChild('modalTemplate', { static: true }) modalTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}



  ngOnInit() {
    // Dummy data
    this.dataSource = [
      { user_id: 1, first_name: 'Ivette', last_name: 'Hansley' },
      { user_id: 2, first_name: 'Kelsey', last_name: 'Wines' },
      { user_id: 3, first_name: 'Janek', last_name: 'Nell' }
    ];
  }


  openCreateModal(): void {
    this.modalTitle = 'Create User';
    this.modalAction = 'Save';
    this.modalUser = {}; // Initialize with an empty object
    this.modalUser.first_name = '';
    this.modalUser.last_name = '';
    this.openModal();
  }

  openEditModal(user: any): void {
    this.modalTitle = 'Edit User';
    this.modalAction = 'Update';
    this.modalUser = { ...user };
    this.openModal();
  }

  /*saveUser(): void {
    // Add or update the user data based on the modal action
    if (this.modalAction === 'Save') {
      // Add new user
      this.dataSource.push(this.modalUser);
    } else if (this.modalAction === 'Update') {
      // Update existing user
      const index = this.dataSource.findIndex(user => user.user_id === this.modalUser.user_id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.dataSource[index] = { ...this.modalUser };
      }
    }

    // Close the modal
    this.closeModal();
  }*/



  saveUser(): void {
    // Add or update the user data based on the modal action
    if (this.modalAction === 'Save') {
      // Add new user
      const newUser = {
        user_id: this.getNextUserId(),
        first_name: this.modalUser.first_name,
        last_name: this.modalUser.last_name
      };
      this.dataSource.push(newUser);
    } else if (this.modalAction === 'Update') {
      // Update existing user
      const index = this.dataSource.findIndex(user => user.user_id === this.modalUser.user_id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.dataSource[index].first_name = this.modalUser.first_name;
        this.dataSource[index].last_name = this.modalUser.last_name;
      }
    }

    // Close the modal
    this.closeModal();

    // Update the table by triggering change detection
    //this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }

  private getNextUserId(): number {
    const maxUserId = Math.max(...this.dataSource.map(user => user.user_id));
    return maxUserId + 1;
  }





  closeModal(): void {
    // Close the modal
    this.isModalOpen = false;
  }

  private openModal(): void {
    // Open the modal
    this.isModalOpen = true;
    this.dialog.open(this.modalTemplate);
  }

  deleteUser(userId: number): void {
    // Delete the user based on user ID
    const index = this.dataSource.findIndex(user => user.user_id === userId);
    if (index !== -1) {
      this.dataSource.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }



  onPageChange(event: any) {
    // Handle pagination change
    console.log('Page changed:', event);

    const pageIndex = event.pageIndex;
    const pageSize = event.pageSize;
    const startIndex = pageIndex * pageSize;
    const endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;

    // Update the displayed data based on the selected page
    //this.dataSource = this.dummyData.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    this.dataSource = this.dataSource.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
  }
}
```

And here is the error I get in browser while I click create, edit button, (and while clicking delete button nothing happens):

```
error-handler.service.ts:26 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'first_name')
    at CompanyCrudComponentComponent_ng_template_19_Template (company-crud-component.component.html:59:62)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:12126:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12011:13)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:13039:17)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12035:9)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:13085:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11801:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12061:13)
    at detectChangesInternal (core.mjs:13229:9)
    at RootViewRef.detectChanges (core.mjs:13741:9)
```

[error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1vOY.png)

[Unresolved variable error in ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBGu3.png)

I tried to access modalUser.first_name, and modalUser.last_name inside ngtemplate but nothing is working for me.
Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: Remove the `let-modalUser` from `<ngTemplate>`?

Comment: thanks @YongShun error is gone now after removing let-modalUser